# Count of rows per group between dates, R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a count of rows that fall on and between two dates (minimum and maximum) per group. The only caveat is each group has a different pair of dates. See example below.

This is my raw dataset.

```
raw <- data.frame ("Group" = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"), "Date" = c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-02", "2017-09-01", "2017-12-31", "2017-05-09"))
```

I would like it to return this...

```
clean <- data.frame ("Group" = c("A", "B"), "Min" = c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-02"), "Max" = c("2017-12-31", "2017-05-09"), "Count" = c(3, 2))
```

How would I be able to do this? The mix and max variable are not crucial, but definitely would like to know how to do the count variable. Thank you!

Comment: So are `Min` and `Max` columns given or are they always just the max and min dates in a group? If it's the former, are those dates given in the same format as in your example, just without the `Count` column? If it's the latter, then dates have nothing to do with the `Count` column and all you need is instances per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date range is given or you want to calculate it from data as well. If later is true then this should do it.

```
require(tidyverse)
raw %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(min_date = min(Date), max_date = max(Date), count = n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Group min_date   max_date   count
  <fct> <date>     <date>     <int>
1 A     2017-01-01 2017-12-31     3
2 B     2017-02-02 2017-05-09     2
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!